# How to underline and color the first letter and the underlining

Tags: sectioning, color, underline

I would like to underline and color only the first letre which is "I" for Information and C for Communication, also color the underlining but this line color all the texte with red !!

`\color{red}{\underline{\color{blue} I}}nformation and \underline{C}ommunication`

Comment: Are you looking for `\textcolor{red}{\underline{\color{blue} I}}nformation and \underline{C}ommunication`? Please don't post code fragments. Always add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead, which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a command with xparse `\Underline` that can also take an optional color value that defaults to a color of your choice, in the example blue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\Underline{O{blue}m}{\underline{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}
\Underline[red]Information and \Underline Communication
\end{document}
```